# How to know specific application run on computer

Tags: c#

I want to check if a  specific application run on  the same computer .

Comment: You mean by reading the current threads? What have you tried?

Comment: I want  it  check using current threads , but my basic requirement is to monitor weather the specific  application is running in the same computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the process name then you can run following code:

```
Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApplication");
if(proc.Length== 0)
{
    // No process with name "MyApplication" is running
}
```

In case your application supports multiple instances then `proc.Length` will give you the number of instances running on the system.

Comment: I am getting an error "system array does not contain  definition for count".

Comment: I have changed the answer a little bit. Try now

Comment: Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome.exe");
            if (proc.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Application  is not running");
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Application Running");
            } '    when i  m running the  application it shows  application not running but chrome  is running

Comment: use "chrome" instead of "chrome.exe"

Comment: @user1713389 is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check for a particular `Exe` is running or not,

```
bool isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("FooAppName")
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainModule.FileName
            .StartsWith(@"c:\Barloc1")) != default(Process);
```

Comment: Good answer Mayank. It could even be better if you explained the two last lines.

Comment: Can you explain it further. I need detailed description .